# Current if/else statement not working correctly and I don't know why not

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, if-statement

My if/else statement recently keep giving me false even when it should return true.

See below my code:

```
const managerStatus = () =>{
  const theManager = "Nick Halding";
  console.log(theManager.length)
  let managerCondition;
  if(theManager.length<=0 || isNaN(theManager) || theManager === undefined){
    managerCondition=false
  }
  else{
    managerCondition=true
  }
  return managerCondition;
}
```

Can clearly see that the length of theManager is bigger than 0 and is not NaN but still return false. It should return true according to me

Comment: `isNaN("Nick Halding")` is true, because `"Nick Halding"` is not a number.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `Number.isNaN`?

Comment: `Number.isNaN("Nick Halding")` is false, because the string is not being coerced into a number before evaluation.

Comment: When dealing with || it's represented as an OR; one one statement match is needed to be true for it to trigger.

Comment: The real question is, why bother with `isNaN` (in either form) if `theManager` is expected to be a name?

Comment: Thank all for your feedback. I understand that I completely misused isNaN. I tried Number.isNaN ("Nick Halding") but still not working yet.

Comment: Not working how? Please make sure the question has a [mcve]

Comment: @HereticMonkey well long story short the name "Nick Halding" comes from localstorage and for some other reason if there is nothing inside that localstorage then it return NaN and not undefined.